# How to get comments from a google site page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get data of the comments on a google site page.

I found an appropriate method "getComments", but it has already been deprecated.
(I tried to use it, but it did not work. Return no array)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#getcomments

Does anyone know the good way to get the comments from a page?
I just want to make a kind of "user comment ranking" from some pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [`Comment`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/comment) Class then the [`getContent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/comment#getcontent) method which returns the content of this comment as a String.

```
var pages = SitesApp.getSite('example.com', 'mysite').getChildren();
var comments = pages[0].getComments();
var content = comments[0].getContent()
```